# Js reload this progress-bar onclick

Tags: javascript, progress-bar, reload

I need to reload this progress-bar after click on the button .. how to do that? thank you

[Demo](https://jsbin.com/vohiwu/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 1):

Add the following line after the start of the `radialProgress` function:

```
$obj.html("");
```

So it will be:

```
function radialProgress($obj, options) {
    $obj.html("");
```

Then just rerun the `radialProgress` function when the reload button is clicked:

```
function reload(){
    //reload again
    $('#time_session').radialProgress("init", {'size': 45, 'fill': 2}).radialProgress("to", {'perc': 100, 'time': 31000,});
}
```

[JSBin](https://jsbin.com/pisiqaloli/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: @MinaMagdy Glad it worked, please accept the answer once you can if it works for you! :D